# Use fundamental theorem of calculus to find derivative of $\int_{X}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t}dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, improper-integrals

I'm supposed to differentiate this $$\int_{X}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{t}dt$$for a wider question on dominant balance + asymptotics but I'm stuck on how to proceed, usual FTC has variable at the top [just minus infront then] but there's never been an integral sign while doing these questions.

I'm not too sure how to continue besides splitting into integral like $$\int_{X}^{a} + \int_{a}^{\infty}$$ which can become : $$ \int_{a}^{\infty}- \int_{a}^{X} $$ but the infinity part messes it up.

Please help, thank you!

Comment: The first part of the split is just a constant, it does not depend on $X$.

Answer (score 0):

The variable doesn't have to be an upper bound or lower bound of the integral. Check out the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) for the more general statement.

As for your improper integral, if it exists then as you have noted,

$$\int_{x}^{\infty} f(t)dt=\int_{x}^{a} f(t)dt+ \int_{a}^{\infty}f(t)dt$$

and the second integral is a constant and has derivative zero while the first integral has derivative w.r.t. $x$ given by $-f(x).$